# can I use Serverless to link an existing AWS lambda function in one repo with an AWS API Gateway code in another repo

Tags: aws-api-gateway, serverless, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I have an existing API Gateway setup using serverless in a repo.
I want to build a lambda function and corresponding to that, an API in API GW.
This lambda function can have multiple features and business logic so want to keep it separate in another repo. Building lambda using serverless seems straightforward. But I don't see a doc on how to link this new lambda to the API in the API Gateway setup. Another point is I want to keep all API exposed in API GW in a single repo whereas multiple lambda functions can be in different repos.

Any pointers appreciated?

Comment: Sure! Why not? Just use your arns

Comment: @DanielA.White any example to share?